# Why security stamp does not logout the user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity. When I block a user account, it should logout immediately.
This is my code:

```
await UserManager.SetLockoutEnabledAsync(user.Id, true);
await UserManager.SetLockoutEndDateAsync(user.Id,DateTime.Today.AddYears(10));
await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);
```

and in `Startup.Auth.cs` :

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<AppUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie))
                }
            });
```

But it does not signout the user. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this problem? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: @AlvinSaldanha, i just posted the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

Instead of calling `UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId)`, set security stamp manually and it logs out user.

```cs
public void UpdateSecurityStamp(string userId)
{
    using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id.Equals(userId));
        if (user != null)
        {
            user.SecurityStamp = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Irfan for posting the solution! Appreciate your help.

Comment: How does this differ with `UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id);`. Aren't you still required to remove the cookies to force immediate logout?

Comment: It's work? i don't figure out it . because i use UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user.Id) and after that i checked the database and it was changed but does'nt work for logout user.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `AuthenticationManager.SignOut()`?

```
var authenticationManager= HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignOut();
```

Comment: I want to sign out a user on the basis of its id. I have admin rights and I can block a user. And when a user is blocked it should be logged out!

Comment: Maybe you will have to call `UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId);` explicitly when the user is validated on his next visit. For this, you can implement the `ICookieAuthenticationProvider`, and call it on  `OnValidateIdentity` callback.

Answer (score 2):

The authentication is connected with a cookie, and **authenticated information's are kept on that cookie**. The cookie is valid for the time you have set, and no matter what you do **this cookie keep user logged in until expired or delete from browser**.

You can delete that cookie from user browser, but if for some reason he keep that cookie, then can still login until the cookie expires. So if your user is already authenticated until the cookie expired is actually logged in.

**If you wish to have immediately logged out**, you need to make some checks **with ajax probably time to time**, if you page use ajax, **or check for the authentication** of the user on each page call, **or create some other table** on database that keep the authentication cookies, and just flag the ones that are not valid any more, and also make check on each call.

I am sorry that I do not have code to show you, is a complicate issue that needs design from your part to fit your needs and your program

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this in Program.cs as another option for

```
builder.Services.PostConfigure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events.OnValidatePrincipal = async context =>
    {
        if (!(context.Principal?.Identity is ClaimsIdentity claimIdentity)) return;
        var mgr = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var user = await mgr.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(claimIdentity.Name);

        if (user != null && claimIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp")?.Value == await mgr.UserManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user))
        {

        }
        else
        {
            context.RejectPrincipal();
            await mgr.SignOutAsync();
        }

    };
});
```

But looking back it seems a bit unnecessary to go the way via the security stamp, if I did again I would add an IsDisabled flag for the user and just check that..